# how to post XML to URL in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

how can i post this xml to url htttp://191.165.0.51:1024/LaunchRemoteXml.ashx in Javascript

```
           <Pipeline Name="MyTest">

                          <Task Name="EmailReport" Timeout="0" Enabled="true" OnFail="Abort" NotifyOnError="true" CodeBase="phynn.Workflow.TaskSmtp@workflow.base.dll">                                                                                         

                          <Smtp>

                                         <Message From="NoOne@directmailers.com" To="xyz@we.com" Subject="TestLaunch" IsHtml="false" Priority="Normal">

                                                        <Body>Hi</Body>

                                         </Message>

                          </Smtp>

                          </Task>

           </Pipeline>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look on this site: https://www.webucator.com/how-to/how-send-receive-xml-data-from-the-server.cfm
Or use jquery

Answer (score 0):

If you limit Vanilla.js only, you can use XMLHttpRequest

You can see how to use it from the [link](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp)

If the xml is a file, you can refer to the [link](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_xmlfile.asp)

Or use Jquery ajax

```
$.ajax({
  url: ajaxurl,
  data: "<test></test>", 
  type: 'POST',
  contentType: "text/xml",
  dataType: "text",
  success : function(data, textStatus, qXHR){
    //do something
  },
  error : function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){  
    //do something
  } 
});
```

For more usage of ajax, please refer to the [link](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)